# Constructor method only working while other variables are static and also not working for first object

Tags: java

I have two classes, one called Soldier, and one called Battlefield, the soldier can spawn at any location that is within the battle field dimensions that are specified by the parameter of the battle field

the variables that put the Soldier object on x and y axis are:

```
private double xPos;
private double yPos;
```

those are within the Soldier class

the method for spawning the Soldier object on the battle field are

```
public Soldier(double speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
    xPos = (int) (Math.random() * Battlefield.getX());
    yPos = (int) (Math.random() * Battlefield.getY());
}
```

And within the battle field class

```
private static double x;
private static double y;

public static double getY() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return y;
}

public static double getX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return x;
}
```

Main Method,

```
public class Battle { 
    //Main method where three battles are run. 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Battlefield k = new Battlefield(100, 100);
        Battlefield b = new Battlefield(100, 100);
        Battlefield c = new Battlefield(100, 100); 
    }
}
```

the problem I am having is this way of doing it is causing the first object to not have any coordinates and everything after that seems fine, but why?

Comment: Post runnable code that illustrates your problem.  Check [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines.

Comment: When do you set BattleField.x and .y? With the code you've shown, they'll always be 0 so Soldier.xPos and .yPos will always be 0 for every Solider.

Comment: within my main method

Comment: `public class Battle {
//Main method where three battles are run.
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Battlefield k = new Battlefield(100, 100);
  Battlefield b = new Battlefield(100, 100);
  Battlefield c = new Battlefield(100, 100);
 }

}`

Comment: did you mean object k?

Comment: It should definitely definitely _not_ be static.

Comment: how is a way to do it?

Comment: @kaanmote In the future please edit your question to add additional code rather than posting it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

From the main class, it looks like you want each Battlefield to have its own state...  So don't make Battlefield.x and Battlefield.y static or else they will all be the same.

Where is the constructor for Battlefield?